# PHP code not executing after a fetching current date from mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to code some manipulations that I need to perform on date format fetched from mySQL, the dates get fetched fine, having converted them TO_DAYS(), the problem is that any code after the line to fetch current date using TO_DAY(CURDATE()) does not get executed, and I cannot seem to understand why? Please Help my code is attached below:

```
//Final Date Calculation

$lastdate=mysql_query("SELECT TO_DAYS(date) FROM ordering WHERE id=1",$conn);
$num_rows_date = mysql_num_rows($lastdate);
while (($row_date = mysql_fetch_array($lastdate, MYSQL_ASSOC)) !== false){
  $ldate[] = $row_date; // add the row in to the results (data) array
}
echo "Total number of records for the given id are: ",$num_rows_date, "<br />";
$ldatefinal=$ldate[$num_rows_date-1]['TO_DAYS(date)'];

echo "Last date in the records for the given ID is ",$ldatefinal,"<br />";
echo "Last date + Prediction days = ",$ldatefinal+$predict,"<br />";


$currentdate=mysql_query("SELECT TO_DAYS(CURDATE())",$conn);

$dcrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($currentdate);

//$dhold=$dcrow['TO_DAYS(CURDATE())'];
echo "Current Date is: ",$dcrow['TO_DAYS(CURDATE())'],"<br /" ;

//UPON EXECUTION NOTHING BELOW GETS ExEcuted ??

echo "Last date + Predicted days = ";




if(($ldatefinal+$predict)-$dcrow['TO_DAYS(CURDATE())'])<10){

echo "Time to Order<br />";
}else{
echo "You Got Gas!!";
}

mysql_close($conn);
```

In essence what this code is suppose to do is to get the delivery dates for a given id, than pick the last delivery date (I tried the LAST() function, but could not get it to work, I believe its for SQL SeRver), once the last delivery date has been determined (in days) it adds $predict value (the code for that is not included, but it is calculating and printing) after the addition of the two values the current date value is subtracted to see if according to a set trigger like say three days something like a push notification needs to be sent (also separate code), but in the code after correctly printing out the current date (echo line) nothing else gets executed, I have even tried putting dummy echo lines below that part to see if they would get printed, they dont!
It seems the following is the problem line in the code (I think)

```
echo "Current Date is: ",$dcrow['TO_DAYS(CURDATE())'],"<br /" ;
```

because every thing (including a simple echo test line does not get executed. Dont know why!

Please Help!
Hamood

Comment: have you `ini_set("display_errors",1)` and `error_reporting(E_ALL)` ? this chould give you a very useful error message

Comment: please stop using mysql functions http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier, thank you for your reply, How whould implement/use the ini_set("display_errors",1) and error(E_ALL)? The only reason I am using mySQL functions is because date field manipulation is quite easy, and I could not find the equalent in PHP.

Comment: add those two lines before any other php functions or commands, just after your very first `<?php` tag. Any errors generated by the subsequent lines will then appear on screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statement is not balanced with `(` and `)`. The code is creating a parse error.

```
   ⬇︎ one more ( needed here
if((($ldatefinal+$predict)-$dcrow['TO_DAYS(CURDATE())'])<10){
```

Comment: I have double checked all the Opening ( have a closing ), unless I am missing something obvious, in additional even the echo test line above the if code does not get printed.

Comment: Maybe you need a third check... You open 2 brackets and you close 3

Comment: @David, got it, You were absolutely right was missing one of the brackets, is there an IDE for PHP that I can use,  that would make stupid mistakes less frequent?

Comment: What OS are you using? `{ } ( ) ;` are often overlooked.

Comment: I am familiar with BBEdit ($) and it's relative TextWrangler (free). BBEdit has coloring that is a good indicator of missing or incorrect  syntax. It is full of features, but also complex.

Comment: As userid53 wrote in comment above, mysql has been deprecated and will someday disappear. [Learn about the PHP replacements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).